# JavaScript array splice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

Hello StackOverflow community!

At the moment I am completly stuck with my code, have try different ways to remove a value from array when picked, I know I have to use splice for it, but for some reason it is not doing what I want it to do

Since the web page is quite difficult to explain as my english aint that good, I have made some screenshots of it, I hope you will get the idea when you see what I want to do!

[image]

This is what the user will see when he visit the webpage, it's basicly a lenormand game. the user has to drag 3 cards in to the gray box below the cards.

[image]

Once he has dragged 3 cards to the box, the user can click on the images (Cards) to turn them (flip)

[image]

This works fine, the only problem is that I don't want the user to pick the same cards twice of even three times, Since I do this with a array, I thought I should use Splice function, but so far, no result!

for the JavaScript code, here is the JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dkk2nqyg/

Somewhere here, I must add the splice

```
$(function () {
var cars = ["2", "3", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "4"];
var rand = cars[Math.floor(Math.random()*cars.length)];

    $(".cards img").each(function(index) {
        $(this).wrap('<div class="front"></div>')
           .parent().wrap('<div class="flipper"></div>')
           .parent().wrap('<div class="flip-container"></div>')
           .append('<div class="back"><img src="./kaart/'+cars[Math.floor(Math.random()*cars.length)]+'.png"</img> </div>');
});
```

I have try'd many solutions, but the problem is that I need to splice it here, atleast, I think:

```
.append('<div class="back"><img src="./kaart/'+cars[Math.floor(Math.random()*cars.length)]+'.png"</img> </div>');
```

I would gladly have this issue resolved and I hope StackOverflow can offer me the help I want :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `splice()` to remove an item from the array, since splice returns an array then you can access the element at the index 0 to get the fetched src value

```
'<div class="back"><img src="./kaart/' + cars.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * cars.length),1)[0] + '.png"</img> </div>'
```

Comment: could you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Thanks! the code is working again, however it does not show me the back of the cards when clicked,  cant find the image
http://i.imgur.com/ZFE0boU.png

Array value is the name of picture btw;)

Comment: @HaltlolXD http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dkk2nqyg/5/ can you create a demo of the problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dkk2nqyg/8/  as you can see, drag all the cards in the box, some will load, some won't load at all;)

Comment: Seems he is not taking the values of the array as url for the images,
http://imgur.com/NEL3MaH

'<div class="back"><img src="./kaart/'+cars.splice(Math.floor(Math.random()*cars.length),1)+'.png"</img> </div>'

Also want to say that I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73064/discussion-between-haltlolxd-and-arun-p-johny).

Comment: Answering, "try `some code here`" is not helpful, in the slightest. Explain the answer, with at least one sentence. It would take less effort than the actual code.

Comment: @NickDugger sorry... there was a chat involved where the issue was discussed in detail...

Answer (score 0):

First, put the random-number in a seperate variable

```
var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random()*cars.length);
var rand = cars[rnd];
```

Then remove that specific item from the array

```
cars.splice(rnd, 1);
```

Cheers
R

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dkk2nqyg/1/
Like this? not working I am afraid, gives me 3x the same cards all the time :p

Comment: could you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi, sorry, there was a little bug in my code, here the link to the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fmszrtez/

Comment: oh sorry, was forgotten to vote +1, obv helped me somewhat + for the effort