# Javascript Splice array value

Tags: javascript

Couple days ago I have asked a question, I will link it here, since it has some explanations about what I want, so you can get a idea what I want to do, 
[JavaScript array splice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072506/javascript-array-splice) 
This is solved now, and the codes works fine, 
But now I want to get the value of the card that has been spliced  ( the cards we get when we drag them in box and click on it )

I thought this would be simple, but I guess I am wrong,

Concrete: I want that the user picks up 3 cards, and this will be mailed to the owner of the website, at the moment I can pick up 3 cards, by using splice the user can not pick multiple the same card, but now I want that the cards that it picks up,  turn into a variable or  something that I can mail them later.

```
$(function () {
var cars = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"];
 var rand = cars[Math.floor(Math.random() * cars.length)];
$(".cards img").each(function (index) {
var src = cars.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * cars.length), 1);
console.log(src, cars.join())
 $(this).wrap('<div class="front"></div>')
.parent().wrap('<div class="flipper"></div>')
.parent().wrap('<div class="flip-container"></div>')
.append('<div class="back"><img src="kaart/'+ src[0] + '.png"</img> </div>');
    });
```

in the html>

```
<script> 
 document.write ("Those will be mailed" + src[0] + "You get it ? "; ) 
</script>
```

JSFiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dkk2nqyg/9/

quite hard to explain, hope you get the idea.

Comment: when do you want to mail?

Comment: well I am looking how to put the picked cards in a variable first, trying to do that atm with document.write, once that is working I will try to add the mail function. Quite new with JavaScript ;)
If you could help me for the mail function I would be happy tho:p

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dkk2nqyg/11/

Comment: What is it exactly doing?
        var selected = $('#dvDest .flipper').map(function(){
            return $(this).data('src')

Comment: see line 10 in script... `.data('src', src[0])` we are storing the src value there

Comment: the `selected` is an array of all the items that are selected

Comment: Any Idea how to convert something in your code?
http://jsfiddle.net/dkk2nqyg/12/

Gives now empty value when click on mail,  I guess its because I changed 

 $("#dvDest").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            ui.helper.addClass("gemaakt");
            if ($(".gemaakt").length == 3) {

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73304/discussion-between-haltlolxd-and-arun-p-johny).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the src value using data api while creating the elements

```
$(".cards img").each(function (index) {
    var src = cars.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * cars.length), 1);
    $(this).wrap('<div class="front"></div>')
    .parent().wrap('<div class="flipper"></div>')
    .parent().wrap('<div class="flip-container"></div>')
    .data('src', src[0])
    .append('<div class="back"><img src="' + src[0] + '.png"</img> </div>');
});
```

then you can get an array of selected items using

```
    var selected = $('#dvDest .flipper').map(function(){
        return $(this).data('src')
    }).get();
    //can use ajax to sent this data to server and then mail it
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dkk2nqyg/11/)