# AJAX - Javascript array to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I know that there are so many to find on the internet, however, I have been trying this for hours now, and still not working, Maybe the community could help me out:)

http://jsfiddle.net/dkk2nqyg/14/

I've got a little explanation in the jsfiddle, else, you can take a look in my previous question, [JavaScript array splice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072506/javascript-array-splice)

Basicly, I want the values from `selected` ( 3 picked up cards ) 
in php, because I want to mail those values;)

```
 $.ajax({
   url: 'data.php',  //I actually want it to be on same page, trying this for debugging
   type: 'post',
   data: {data : selected},
   success: function(data) {
        alert("worked");
   }
});
```

in the data.php :

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
  foreach($data as $d){
     echo $d;
  }
?>
```

I would like that I don't even need that data.php but just 1 page, so in the index.php, is that even possible?

Edit: Please, link a JsFiddle, would really help!

Comment: `console.log(data)` instead of `alert("worked")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the ajax request should be within the click handler

```
$('#mail').click(function () {
    console.log($('#dvDest .flipper').get())
    var selected = $('#dvDest .flipper').map(function () {
        return $(this).data('src')
    }).get();
    alert(selected)
    $.ajax({
        url: 'data.php', //I actually want it to be on same page, trying this for debugging
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            data: selected
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("worked");
        }
    });
})
```

then in server side loop through the array like<sub>(Not sure about the PHP syntax)</sub>

```
<?php
  foreach($_POST['data'] as $d){
     echo $d;
  }
?>
```

Comment: O hello Again! 
Seems you are quite my hero this week, sorry for the questions and stuff, doing a internship and they make me work with javascript, wich I don't really have on school, so quite hard ^^ 

Any idea how I can avoid data.php and do it on same page?

Comment: @HaltlolXD you can check whether it is a post request.. also the presents of the `data` param then do the mailing else execute the script for listing

Answer (score 0):

you can write a condition as if request object have post values then

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
 foreach($data as $d){
  echo $d;
}
```

else your homepage display code

So,index.php is enough

Comment: Gives me Notice: Undefined index: data in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 126

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 127

Comment: i just pasted your code    only   my answer is to achieve in a single file instead of 2 php files

Comment: well i want to achieve it in 1 file tho, could you upload me a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

For using a single page, eg: index.php

at the top of index.php you do:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // Your code goes here
    exit();
}
```